# How do I simulate a registration form submission while testing?

Tags: testing, integration-tests

I'm trying to figure out how to do an integration test on the registration form by simulating a registration with something like:

```php
public function test_registration_form_submission_valid() {
    // Simulate registration form submission
    deactivate_plugins( 'new-user-approve/new-user-approve.php' );
    $response = wp_remote_post(
        'http://127.0.0.1/wp-login.php?action=register',
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'timeout' => 45,
            'httpversion' => '1.0',
            'blocking' => true,
            'headers' => array(),
            'body' => array(
                'user_login' => 'testuser',
                'user_email' => 'testuser@example.com',
            ),
        )
    );

    // Check for errors
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $this->fail( $response->get_error_message() );
    }

    // Check if user was created
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', 'testuser' );
    echo(var_dump($user));
    $this->assertNotEmpty( $user );

    // Clean up
    if ($user) { wp_delete_user( $user->ID ); }
}
```

This doesn't work because the user will get created on the live site on my local machine so the `get_user_by` returns nothing because that's run on the test version of WordPress running in `/tmp` using the test database.

What I need to do is to try to simulate a registration form submission on the database spun up by `WP_UnitTestCase`. Not sure if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the "register_new_user" function so there does not appear to be a need for simulating the registration form. So I can do something like this:

```
    public function test_registration_errors {                                                                                                            
       $user_login = 'newuser';
       $user_email = 'newuser@example.cc';               
       $errors = register_new_user ( $user_login, $user_email
       $this->assertIsNotInt( $errors );
    }
```